# Two-Way databinding dynamic object on winform controls

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, expandoobject

I want to databind a Dynamic object to a control in a winform app. So far I got it somewhat working, it does seems to databind "the first time", **but then when I change the property value it does not take effect on the binded control**, and that's the problem I can't overcome.

Here is the code, if you create a new winform app with a textbox and a button you can test it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public dynamic ViewData { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.ViewData = new ExpandoObject();

            this.ViewData.Test = "test1";

            var bind = new Binding("Text", this.ViewData, null);
            bind.Format += (o, c) => c.Value = this.ViewData.Test;
            bind.Parse += (o, c) => this.ViewData.Test = c.Value;
            textBox1.DataBindings.Add(bind);

            this.ViewData.Test = "test2";

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewData.Test = "test3";
        }
    }
```

For the record, if I change the control value, it'd reflected on the dynamic property, which is OK too.

For the sake of completeness, [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375945/binding-custom-properties-values-of-an-instance-of-expandoobject-to-a-net-wind) gave me this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, Binding cannot respond to your DataSource's property changes as it is not aware of the name of the property it needs to listen to, because the property name is not provided in Binding's constructor (3rd parameter) - by design.

To overcome this issue, basically, we need to listen to changes of DataSource and inform or force Binding to read value again. Fortunately, Binding class has a public method ReadValue, which forces Binding to read the value from DataSource again.

If you extend your code with the following line e.g. before binding is added to the DataBindings collection, that could solve the two-way bindings.

```
((INotifyPropertyChanged)this.ViewData).PropertyChanged += (sender2, e2) =>
    {
        if (e2.PropertyName == "Test")
        {
            bind.ReadValue();
        }
    };
```

At the end, all these workarounds can be encapsulated into a nice helper method to hide the details and make it reusable as much as possible.